# AWS ELB Crashes everyday on the same time

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, nginx, uwsgi, amazon-elb

I have no explanation for that.

We are running an ELB that contains 6 `uWSGI+NGINX` static-ip instances on AWS.
On the attached image you can see that everyday on the exact same time the load changes (no idea why) and then ELB marks servers and `outOfService` even though they FUNCTION CORRECTLY when hitting the instances directly.

Instances are `m4.xlarge` (16.0 GB, 13 units, 4 cores) with `Centos 7` ami. `iptables` drops null packets.

IPTables Rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -f -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
```

Requests:
[image: sum of requests]
ELB 5xx:
[image: sum of 5xx]

Our traffic load does not change (at least it doesn't should) along the day, its pretty stable as we work globally.

Perhaps the problem is caused by `uWSGI` config?
See attached config:

```
<pre>
[uwsgi]
    vhost = true
    uid = username
    base =      /path/to/app
    wsgi-file = /path/to/app
    chdir = %(base)
    chown-socket = nginx:nginx
    uid = nginx
    gid = nginx
    chmod-socket = 777
    socket = /var/run/webpage.com.uwsgi.socket
    plugin = python
    master = True
    callable = app
    threads = 10
    vacuum = true
    die-on-term = true
    max-requests = 500
    thread-stacksize = 2048
    cheaper-algo = spare2
    cheaper = 4
    cheaper-initial = 8
    workers = 16
    cheaper-step = 1
    buffer-size = 30000
    disable-logging = True
</pre>
```

NGINX Config (i know about the CORS, its on purpose):

```
<pre>
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    #server {
    #    listen       80 default_server;
    #    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    #    server_name  _;
    #    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    #    location / {
    #    }

    #    error_page 404 /404.html;
    #        location = /40x.html {
    #    }

    #    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #        location = /50x.html {
    #    }
    #}
}
</pre>
```

I'll be happy to provide more information if needed..

Comment: Have you turned on logging for the ELB, and reviewed the logs?

Comment: I'm pretty new with AWS, had no idea about this feature! I'll try it right away!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've activated the elb logs. but these are just access logs - what anomaly would you be looking for? it will be pretty hard to get any insight from these logs..

Comment: They are "just" access logs of all the pages requested and their load times... which *should* make the nature of the problem readily apparent, if it has anything to do with the traffic hitting your site... because there are probably certain requests that are harbingers of doom.  It seems very unlikely that this is a problem with ELB itself.  Your servers may appear to be functioning fine, but this is likely not really the case.  In any event, you're flying blind if you try to troubleshoot without the logs.

Comment: I'm interested in what your nginx logs look like- do they show *anything* different during that time period? more errors? more hits? different hits? how's the memory and cpu profile on those machines during the day? is there anything in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`? (I'd suggest at least trialing newrelic)